# suggestion for a isometric javascript framework/engine

Tags: javascript, isometric

I will be creating a small isometric game with JS. There are a lot of different frameworks and engines out there...

Please help me to find the right one for my needs:

In my game the world will not be expendable - so the ground and its borders are already given in the beginning and can't be changed.
One can place an object from a library on the ground and also delete it. 
One can zoom in/out and drag the whole map (if its zoomed)
That's basically it.

I've seen these engines (but I'm sure there are more):
http://craftyjs.com/, http://www.prelude-prod.fr/demo/pp3diso/, http://www.isogenicengine.com/, http://jsiso.com/

Please help me to find the right one.

Comment: Probably better asked on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com

Comment: I see. Admin, could you please move this topic to  gamedev.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: @Jongware No, which technology to use questions are off topic on GDSE, just like a "Which IDE to use" would be off topic here.

Comment: @Byte56: that's fair. Perhaps http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ then. The OP seems to have a good idea of what features are wanted; perhaps it would be easiest to read about "Features" on each of the URLs, compare them against the wish-list, and pick the one with the most up-votes.

Comment: @Jongware: sure I could do that - but isn't this what the exchange of experience is for? I mean there are a lot of people who already know how to handle some problem and someone doesn't - so he asks.... I don't understand what is so strange about it...

Comment: It is not a strange thing to ask, it's just off-topic on Stackoverflow; thus my suggestions for other sites. See the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page: "SO is for *programming* questions." It would be a different issue if you were programming your own isometric engine and had a problem with that.

Comment: I see - you are totally right! Thanks for that

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late-night-answer but I implemented a library some time ago. It provides you the basic isometric shapes as well as some methods to help you initialize them. It might not be exactly what are you looking for, but it allows you to do the basic things quite well. See the [Wiki page](https://github.com/GeorgeGkas/isometricObelisk.js/wiki) for more informations.

[IsometricObelisk.js](https://github.com/GeorgeGkas/isometricObelisk.js)